# textbox replace text

Tags: c#

It give me an error, don't know why. I want to replace `'` with `"`.

```
try
{
     txtCS.Text.Replace("'", """);
}
catch
{
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `Replace` method returns a string because strings themselves are immutable. This means that instead of changing the existing string (`txtCS.Text`), it creates a new string object and so you need to assign that new string object to the textbox.

Also, you're missing the escape character in your quotes. By adding a `\`, you can use the `"` character, otherwise the compiler thinks you're closing the string.

```
txtCS.Text = txtCS.Text.Replace("'", "\"");
```